# Header elements put in one row

Tags: html, material-design

I have 7 elements which I want to put in my html header section.

But when I put those 7 elements one by one in my header section, the elements are not situating on a single row.

**This is the structure what I want to do :**

[image]

**But the Output is looking like that --**

[image]

This is my code --

```
  <header>
    <div class="mdl-layout-icon">
      <!-- icon -->
      <img src="public/images/bower.png" alt="office" height="42" width="82">
      <form action="#">
        <!-- TextField -->
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="searchText">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="searchText">Search</label>
        <!-- Button -->
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">Search</button>
      </form>
      <!-- Shopping Cart -->
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE8CC;</i>
      <!-- Quantity -->
      <label for="quantity">quantity</label>
      <!-- Price -->
      <label for="price">price</label>
      <!-- CheckOut -->
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE877;</i>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Any one knows how can I fix this issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form element is a block by default. Set its style to `display: inline`, or wrap header with your form (so all elements are inside the form).

Comment: Than you have other style conflicting. Look at this example [on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nutw6gsj/).

Comment: now I know the problem was the text input fields was talking the whole row